# XSL copy template and add new attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, addition, nodes

The input XML:

```
<a>
    <b1>
        <c1 width="500" height="200">
            <d1 data="null" />
        </c1>
    </b1>
    <b2 />
</a>
```

I want to **copy** all of the attributes from `b1/c1` to `b2/c1` **AND** **add** a new attribute (`length`).
The output XML should be:

```
<a>
    <b1>
        <c1 width="500" height="200">
            <d1 data="null" />
        </c1>
    </b1>
    <b2>
        <c1 width="500" height="200" length="2">
            <d1 data="null" />
        </c1>
    </b2>
</a>
```

I have a code, which **copy** all from b1/c1 to b2/c2 BUT **without** adding a new atttribute (`length`):

```
<xsl:template match="/a/b2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="/a/b1/c1" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And I tried to **add attribute** to the copy part, but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="/a/b2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="/a/b1/c1" >
            <xsl:attribute name="length">2</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start with an identity template, then override the b2 node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../b1/c1" mode="test"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c1" mode="test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="length">2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sorry, I edited the input xml: there is no c1 in the b2, that is why i need the copy-of. so how to do it now?

Comment: happy to have helped.

Comment: it is not perfect :/ I got this 3 new attribute to my b2/c1: `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:util="util" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"`

Comment: and I edited the question, the input and output XML changed: c1 has d1, and if I use your code, b2/c1 will not have d1. could you help me with this?

Comment: I have edited again my answer. I have tested that code against your input using Xalan 2.7.1. See http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHY

Answer (score 2):

Re your edited question - try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../b1/c1" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c1" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="length">2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```